# Console output displays ASCII values instead of expected digits of a number

Tags: c++, string, vector

I'm facing an issue with printing the individual digits of two big integer numbers in C++. The numbers are up to 600 digits in length, and I'm trying to store and manipulate them using strings and vectors. However, when I attempt to loop through the vector and print the digits, I get unexpected results – the ASCII values of the digits are being displayed on the console. I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve this issue.

Here's an example of the issue I encountered:

For the first string, I input the numbers 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1, but on the console, I get the following result:

```
[0]57
[1]56
[2]55
[3]54
[4]53
[5]52
[6]51
[7]50
[8]49
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::string Sum_Of_Two_Long_Integers()
{
  std::string First_String;
  std::string Second_String;
  std::string Result_String;

  std::cout << "Please enter the first number: ";
  std::getline(std::cin, First_String);
  std::cout << "Please enter the second number: ";
  std::getline(std::cin, Second_String);

  std::vector<int> First_String_Vector(First_String.length());
  std::vector<int> Second_String_Vector(Second_String.length());

  for (int Counter = 0; Counter < First_String_Vector.size(); ++Counter)
  {
    First_String_Vector[Counter] = First_String[Counter] - '0'; // Convert char to integer
    Second_String_Vector[Counter] = Second_String[Counter] - '0'; // Convert char to integer
    std::cout << "[" << Counter << "]" << First_String_Vector[Counter] << std::endl;
  }

  return Result_String;
}

int main()
{
  std::string Result_String = Sum_Of_Two_Long_Integers();
  std::cout << "Result = " << Result_String << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I believe the issue might be related to how I'm handling the ASCII values of the characters. Can someone help me understand how to correctly extract and print the individual digits without encountering this ASCII representation?

Comment: Use a bignum library. Like [GMP](https://gmplib.org) or another similar library - there are several (but `GMP` is pretty darn good, IMHO).

Comment: @EJoshuaS I want some one to tell me how to fix my code .I do not want to take anyone else's code.

Comment: @moda there is *no way* that your code is *ever* going to match the performance of `GMP` or similar libraries that have had tens (if not hundreds) of man years invested in them by *experts*. Just use a library already, don't try to roll your own solution - if you make it work it's going to be slow and trying to make it fast could easily result in years of work. Just stand on the shoulder of giants and move on to more important tasks.

Comment: @moda If this is a homework assignment that you have to write your own code you should mention that to avoid the long discussion about using some other big math library.

Comment: @moda -- You could have avoided the entire discussion of "big number libraries' by seeing that your issue has absolutely nothing to do with big number libraries.  You are printing the integer version of ASCII characters, and the issue could have been duplicated with a 2 or 3 line `main` function, without any mention of big number libraries.

Comment: Do you really need the vectors to do the calculation? if you do (and think it will help) you may want to create a to vector function and to string function to convert back and forth,

Comment: @JesperJuhl You are right but I have to wright my own code because it is a homework . That was my bad . I had to mention that it was a homework

Comment: @moda Advice -- the title given to this thread does not describe your actual issue ("How to calculate the sum of two big integers").  You should do more debugging and inspection of your own code to determine the real issue, thus when doing so, create a better and more appropriate title to the thread.  Persons now doing a search on SO will come across this page, and see that the issue has nothing to do with adding up big integers.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am a new in this site so I do not know exactly what do  . Can I now change the title ?

Comment: @moda Edit the title by pressing the "edit" link below the text window.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks a lot but I am a new English learner and I face a problem with express what exactly  the title is supposed to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
First_String_Vector[Counter] = First_String[Counter] ;
Second_String_Vector[Counter] = Second_String[Counter] ;
```

The digits are stored as ASCII in you string, you should convert to integer before placing them into the vector.

This would do the trick:

```
First_String_Vector[Counter] = First_String[Counter] - '0';
Second_String_Vector[Counter] = Second_String[Counter] - '0';
```

I would also add a check for valid input before populating your vectors to make sure that you only read digits:

```
if(First_String[Counter] < '0' || First_String[Counter] > '9' ||
   Second_String[Counter] < '0' || Second_String[Counter] > '9')
{
    std::cout << "Invalid input\n";
    return "":// Or better throw an exception
}
```

**EDIT:** `'6'` isn't equal to `6`. The first one is a char, its value is ASCII for character '6', and the second is the integer 6.

[ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) is an encoding. Characters are mapped to some numbers. Value for '0' is 48, '1' is 49, ..., '9' is 57

To be even more precise C++ does not guarantee to use ASCII encoding (though I don't know of an implementation that does not use it), but it does guarantee that '0'...'9' have contiguous integer values. So `'6' - '0'` will give us integer 6.

Comment: That solved my problem thanks a lot but could you please tell me why adding  -'0' solve the problem and could you please tell me where I am supposed to  add a check for valid input  to make sure that First_String[Counter] >= '0' && First_String[Counter] <= '9' and the same for Second_String.

Comment: @moda -- **text** is encoded with numeric values. If you want to interpret a text character as a numeric value you have to convert the **encoded representation** into the corresponding value. That is, `'9'` does not necessarily have the value `9`. But the C and C++ languages guarantee that the encodings of the characters `'0' .. '9'` are contiguous and increasing. So `'0' - '0'` will give you the number `0`, and, since `'1'` is one more than `'0'`, `'1' - '0'` gives you the value `1`. Etc.

Comment: @moda sorry for the late reply, updated the answer